# Json::Value gets changed when returned?

Tags: c++, json, c++11, jsoncpp

Hi I have this method that returns a Json::Value

```
Json::Value simplifyDate(const Json::Value& data) {
    Json::Value value;
    if (data.get("$JSNType", "").asString() == "date") {
        value = data["value"];
    }
    return value;
}
```

If I inspect `value` before returning it is `{"dayOfTheMonth":1,"month":3,"year":2017}`

But in the calling method:

```
Json::Value value = simplifyDate(data);
```

`value` gets this value: `{"dayOfTheMonth":0,"month":0,"year":0}`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: for answer your question it's necessary to look at json::value definition. It seems to me a problem in move/copy ctor.

Answer (score 0):

doing

```
value = Json::Value(data["value"]);
```

instead of `value = data["value"]` seems to solve the issue